# Inconsistent security behaviour on IIS

Tags: wcf-security, iis-express

We have a secured WCF service with WsHttpBinding, Client & Server certificates & transport security with Claim Based Authorization.

Everything works fine 50 % of the time. When we do request to a secure endpoint, we get the correct response. But if we send the same request again immidiatly after the first we get the following response:

```
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.
```

If we then send a request again, we get normal behaviour. So the odd requests work and the even not.

But after some more investigation in the problem. We noticed that if there is at least 1:40 minutes between the previous request, we don't get the error response.

What we can confirm from the debugger and logging. The client sends the credentials to the service. We don't enter System.ServiceModel if we have the Authentication response. In the IIS trace logs we get this on a good request:

```
Authentication: SSL/PCT 
User from token: Domain\CertifacteUserName
```

and this on a bad request:

```
Authentication: NOT_AVAILABLE 
User from token:
```

Also in the IIS Trace logging. If we send the second request, we see that the ConnId and RawConnId are the same on both requests. And if we make multiple successful request (By allowing some time between requests) they are different for each request.

It seems to me IIS is not getting the Credentials we send, when they are there. Is this due to caching? Or something else? Does anyone has a solution.

Comment: Preben, did you ever resolve this? I'm curious what solution you might have found.

Comment: We were not able to resolve this issue. However when we deployed to test and production, this was not an issue. Using a full IIS instead of IIS express solved the issue for us.